# Dockerfile Image The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y mysqld-server' returned a non-zero code: 100

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, docker, nginx

I want to make a docker image with this spec:

1. Ubuntu : 16.04 / Latest
2. PHP 7.x
3. nginx : Latest mySQL 5.x
4. Expose Port 80 & 443
5. Directory / Source

Optional :

1. VIM
2. PHP Composer

My Dockerfile:

```
# Download base image ubuntu 16.04
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Update Ubuntu Software repository
RUN apt-get update

# Install PHP, nginx, mySQL
RUN apt-get install -y nginx php7.0-fpm && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install MySQL and set default root password
RUN echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password  password mypassword' | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password mypassword' | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server

# Define the ENV variable
ENV nginx_vhost /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
ENV php_conf /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
ENV nginx_conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Enable php-fpm on nginx virtualhost configuration
COPY default ${nginx_vhost}
RUN sed -i -e 's/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/g' ${php_conf} && \
echo "\ndaemon off;" >> ${nginx_conf}

RUN mkdir -p /run/php && \
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html && \
chown -R www-data:www-data /run/php

# Volume configuration
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/sites-enabled", "/etc/nginx/certs", "/etc/nginx/conf.d", "/var/log/nginx", "/var/www/html"]

# Configure Services and Port
COPY start.sh /start.sh
CMD ["./start.sh"]

EXPOSE 80 443
```

I get this error message when I built it

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 5.632 kB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 2d696327ab2e
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b58709c2b7b9
Step 3 : RUN apt-get install -y nginx php7.0-fpm &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3d58b4fac924
Step 4 : RUN echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password  password mypassword' | debconf-set-selections
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 85256efe3bd3
Step 5 : RUN echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password mypassword' | debconf-set-selections
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d1f71eeacbe2
Step 6 : RUN apt-get install -y mysqld-server
 ---> Running in 9dba6ce0c59a
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package mysqld-server
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y mysqld-server' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the line `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`. You are deleting the lists that have been fetched by the `apt-get update`. You then try to install a package using apt. This will fail.

You need to move `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/` after the line that installs mysql-server.

```
# Download base image ubuntu 16.04
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Update Ubuntu Software repository
RUN apt-get update

# Install PHP, nginx, mySQL
RUN apt-get install -y nginx php7.0-fpm

# Install MySQL and set default root password
RUN echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password  password mypassword' | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password mypassword' | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Define the ENV variable
ENV nginx_vhost /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
ENV php_conf /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
ENV nginx_conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Enable php-fpm on nginx virtualhost configuration
COPY default ${nginx_vhost}
RUN sed -i -e 's/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/g' ${php_conf} && \
echo "\ndaemon off;" >> ${nginx_conf}

RUN mkdir -p /run/php && \
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html && \
chown -R www-data:www-data /run/php

# Volume configuration
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/sites-enabled", "/etc/nginx/certs", "/etc/nginx/conf.d", "/var/log/nginx", "/var/www/html"]

# Configure Services and Port
COPY start.sh /start.sh
CMD ["./start.sh"]
```